# Extract an information from a generated array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

The `createTour()` function generates a virtual Tour ID.
By including `print_r($buffer)` or `var_dump($buffer)` in the function, I can see the generated `id`.

Here is how the generated array looks like:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(344) "{"type":"TOUR_CREATED","details":{"class":"models.pano.VirtualTour","created":1582643053000,"modified":1582643053800,"id":"5e55376dff02e155e6732614","itemID":"5e55376dff02e155e6732615","userID":"58e4c9d15f6266268511ac5d","agentID":"58e4c9d15f6266268511ac5e","name":"pasda","panoramas":[],"limitedAccess":false,"grantAccessAutomatically":false}}" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "{"type":"TOUR_ALREADY_EXIST"}" }
```

What I would like to do is to extract this information and include it in the `createRoomAndPano()` function, precisely {**here**} `curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.immoviewer.com/rest/v1/tour/{here}/pano");`

The question is : how to extract the information contained in `id` from the  generated array in PHP?

Comment: You start by realizing that you have JSON in string form here - so you will need to decode that first of all. After that, this boils down to very simple navigation in a nested data structure.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted, $buffer is an array of JSON strings.
Doing a `

```
$foo = json_decode($buffer[0], true);
```

would return an associative array, that you can use to extract the ID like

```
$id = $foo['details]['id'];
```

and set it

```
curl_setopt($ch_1, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://app.immoviewer.com/rest/v1/tour/'.$id.'/pano');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @AfricaOMM All I did was format this guys answer so it was a little more readable and then post a link so he could check out the documentation for himself.